# Статические файлы в контейнере с django и nginx не подгружаются!

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

Не могу найти причину, почему упорно не подгружается статика в контейнере...

**docker-compose.yml**

```
volumes:
  pgdata:
  static:
  media:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.db
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  django:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: django
    expose:
      - "8000"
      - "587"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    command: sh -c "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
                    python3 manage.py makemigrations &&
                    python3 manage.py migrate &&
                    gunicorn --workers=4 --reload --max-requests=1000 userauth.wsgi -b "0.0.0.0:8000""
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    working_dir: /app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    depends_on:
      - django

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.dev
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/data

  celery-worker:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: celery-worker
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - media:/app/media
    command: celery -A userauth worker --loglevel=info --logfile=./logs/celery-worker.log
    depends_on:
      - redis

  celery-beat:
      build: .
      container_name: celery-beat
      env_file:
          - ./env/.env.dev
      command: celery -A userauth beat --loglevel=info --logfile=./logs/celery-beat.log
      volumes:
          - media:/app/media
          - ./:/app
      depends_on:
        - redis
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

**nginx.conf**

```
    server django:8000;
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name localhost;



       location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_pass http://django;

        }

       location /static/ {
           root /app;
        }

       location /media/ {
           root /app;
        }

}
```

**nginx/dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG=True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

в терминале:

```
django         | Bad Request: /
django         | Not Found: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
django         | Not Found: /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css
django         | Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
```

консоль браузера:

```
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js» не удалась.

Ресурс с «http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/responsive.css» был заблокирован из-за несоответствия MIME-типа («text/html») (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```